# How to use Lenses to traverse and assign to some (but not all) elements in a Map

Tags: haskell, lenses

I've been trying to use lenses and containers together with some success but i have hit the limitations of my understanding trying to use filtering traversals of Data.Map - i can change individual instances in the map or traverse all instances but i can't work out how to act on some identifiable partition (ie keys in a range).

Essentially i'm trying to do something similar with maps to what Gabriel Gonzalez excellent lenses tutorial does with lists [1]

Here's a working skeleton of my code with the `traverseSome` function which i don't know how to write commented out. Any help gratefully received!

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes      #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set

type CharSet = Set.Set Char
type MapOfSets = Map.Map Int CharSet

data DB = DB { _mos  :: MapOfSets } deriving (Show, Eq)

makeLenses ''DB

initDB :: DB
initDB =  DB { _mos  = Map.fromList (zip [1..5] (repeat Set.empty)) }

add2Map :: Int -> CharSet -> State DB ()
add2Map i cs = mos.ix i %= (Set.union cs)

traverseAll :: Traversal' DB CharSet
traverseAll = mos.traversed

add2MapsAll :: CharSet -> State DB ()
add2MapsAll cs = traverseAll %= (Set.union cs)

--        <problematic part>          
{-
traverseSome :: [Int] -> Int -> Traversal' DB MapOfSets
traverseSome ids i = _

add2MapsSome :: [Int] -> CharSet -> State DB ()
add2MapsSome ids cs = mos.(traverseSome ids 2) %= (Set.union cs)
-}         
--        </problematic part>

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let db = initDB
  let bar = Set.fromList ['a'..'g'] :: CharSet
  let baz = Set.fromList ['f'..'m'] :: CharSet
  let quux = Set.fromList ['n'..'z'] :: CharSet

  let db2 = execState (add2Map 5 bar) db
  let db3 = execState (add2MapsAll baz) db
  -- let db4 = execState (add2MapsSome [1,3] quux) db

  print db2
  print db3
  -- print db4
```

[1] http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html

Comment: Can't you just use ```mapM_ (`add2Map` cs) ids```?  Seems like the easiest way to me.

Comment: Did you mean `traverseSome :: [Int] -> Int -> Traversal' DB CharSet`?

Comment: Also, what does `Int` do in the type of `traverseSome`?

Comment: @bheklilr: i missed that possibility too but i was really looking to see how to do it with lenses.

Comment: @AndrásKovács - the code in comments was just a sketch of what i thought it might look like, including wrong sig (MapOfSets) and the idea that i might need to pass the index into the traversal somehow (Int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean

```
traverseSome :: [Int] -> Traversal' DB CharSet
```

Here's a more general version

```
keys :: Ord k => [k] -> IndexedTraversal' k (Map.Map k a) a
keys ks f m = go ks <&> \m' -> foldr (uncurry M.insert) m m'
  where
    go []     = pure []
    go (i:is) = case Map.lookup i m of
                  Just a  -> (:) . (,) i <$> indexed f i a <*> go is
                  Nothing -> go is
```

which is very similar to `ordinals` from `Data.Vector.Lens` (my version doesn't nub duplicates, so make sure the list doesn't have duplicates). `go` goes through the list of indices and looks them up in the map, adding the index as it goes. The `foldr` bit goes through the list of edited elements and `inserts` them back into the original map.

You can write your's as

```
traverseSome :: [Int] -> IndexedTraversal' Int DB CharSet
traverseSome is = mos . keys is

add2MapsSome :: [Int] -> CharSet -> State DB ()
add2MapsSome is cs = traverseSome is %= Set.union cs
```

---

If you did want

```
traverseSome :: [Int] -> Lens' DB MapOfSets
```

this can be written as (note you shouldn't add new keys to the `Map` or you'll break the lens laws)

```
submap :: Ord k => [k] -> Lens' (Map.Map k a) (Map.Map k a)
submap ks f m = f (Map.fromList as) <&> (<> m)
  where as = Maybe.mapMaybe (\i -> (,) i <$> Map.lookup i m) ks
```

which could be used to write `keys` (but would be less efficient because you make an intermediate `Map`):

```
keys :: Ord k => [k] -> IndexedTraversal' k (Map k a) a
keys ks = submap ks . itraversed
```

---

edit: version without intermediate lists:

```
keys :: Ord k => [k] -> IndexedTraversal' k (Map.Map k a) a
keys ks f m = go ks
  where
    go []     = pure m
    go (i:is) =
      case Map.lookup i m of
        Just a  -> Map.insert i <$> indexed f i a <*> go is
        Nothing -> go is
```

Comment: wonderfully comprehensive answer thanks so much! Lots to learn from this.

Answer (score 1):

Map is an [instance of `TraversableWithIndex`](http://traverseSome%20::%20[Int]%20-%3E%20Traversal'%20DB%20CharSet%20traverseSome%20ids%20=%20mos%20.%20itraversed%20.%20indices%20(%60Set.member%60%20idSet)%20where%20%20%20idSet%20=%20Set.fromList%20ids), so you can use `itraversed` to also traverse the keys. [`indices`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.9.1/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#v:indices) can be used to narrow down the range of keys.

```
traverseSome :: [Int] -> Traversal' DB CharSet
traverseSome ids = mos . itraversed . indices (`Set.member` idSet) where
  idSet = Set.fromList ids
```

Note that `itraversed` is different from `traversed` here. `traversed` is always indexed by the ordinal positions of the elements, while `itraversed` may be indexed by a variety of key types depending on the data structure.

Comment: Ah yes, I meant to mention this. Note that you need traverse the whole map in this solution (whereas mine only picks out the chosen elements).